# Convert MySQL latin1_bin with Hibernate to utf-8

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, utf-8, latin1

I have a MySQL DB (READ-ONLY, NO DB CHANGES) with many varchar fields encoding in latin1_bin. I can not change any DB structure or create any view. I get access to this fields with Hibernate. How can I set the hibernate converting to UTF-8??

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
```

this don't work.

I don't want to convert any field directly in my application, because that are so much String fields.

Thanks for your Answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change your **latin1_bin** String to **utf-8** String.See sample;

```
public class StringHelper {
    public static String convertToUTF8(String s) {
        String out = null;
        try {
            out = new String(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
        } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return out;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String latinString = "hÃ©llo";//just sample not sure real latin string or not.
        String utf8String = StringHelper.convertToUTF8(latinString);
        System.out.println(utf8String);

    }

}
```